# File format issue in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I have to parse a file in perl. The file is in UTF 16 le format, however I need the file in UTF 8 format. I have converted the file and stored it in a new file, however I get an issue with the new line character.

In the original file each new line is represented as `0d 00 0a 00` (carriage return and new line) however in the converted file I only see 0d instead of `0d 0a`. The problem with this is that the next time I try to read the file, it reads the whole file as 1 line. 
To convert the file, all I am doing is to read the file in UTF 16 format and write it in UTF 8. Could you please tell me how I can add the `0a` at the end?

Comment: You've described the result, but you haven't shown your code. Please show your code.

Comment: Are you perhaps `chomp`ing your input (thus removing the LF and leaving only the CR)?

Comment: Just use `iconv` to convert your file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I managed to put in a new line character by just printing a new line. The code I was using was

```
open IN, '<:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)', $input;
open (OUT,"> $sOutFile");
my $count = 0; 
while ( defined ($sLine = <IN>))
{
    if ($count == 0)    // Delete first line as not needed
    {
       $count = 1;
       next;
    }
chomp $sLine;
print OUT $sLine."\x0A";    // To get new line
}
```

I know this is not the best way (even for removing the first line), but it worked.

I apologize for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown any code (which I suggest you do, for more relevant suggestions), I would blindly recommend this: [Encode::Unicode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aUnicode).

Comment: [piconv](http://p3rl.org/piconv) contained in the same distribution is the appropriate command-line tool for encoding conversions.